# Conversion of time formats i sheets/excel

Tags: excel, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, data-conversion

I would like to find a formula which translates a date and time raw text output on the form:

```
May 22, 2018 at 02:17PM
```

To something more digestible by google sheets, like:

```
22/5/2018 14:17:00
```

Is this possible? I'm talking conversion of written month to counted month, from 12-hour clock to 24-hour clock, and rearranging of the day/month. I feel like it is a little ambiguous, but would it be possible?

Answer (score 4):

Please use the following

```
=--REGEXREPLACE(A2,"at","")
```

Since dates/times are numbers, your result will be in the form of `43242.5951388889`

You then format the result from the menu `Format--> Number--> Date time` for a standard format.
You can also further choose  `More Formats--> More date and time formats` for more options.

*(If still in trouble please let us know)*

---

**Addition**
As suggested by [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) at his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64442265/conversion-of-time-formats-i-sheets-excel#comment113950272_64442421) and **since `REGEXREPLACE` is more greedy compared to `SUBSTITUTE`**, one could also use

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(A2,"at","")
```

Comment: What if OP has a different locale set? Won't be able to use English month names in formatting.

Comment: It's a good answer. I upvoted, but personally won't be able to test it since my locale does **not** recognize `PM` nor `May` unfortunately =). Btw, I think you can get a performance increase with `SUBSTITUTE()` instead of `REGEXREPLACE`.

Comment: @kishkin *"What if OP has a different locale set? Won't be able to use English month names in formatting.*". I would tend to share your concerns. Still. This is not what is asked for by the OP. I personally tend to go for compact, minimal, functional solutions. In this case -in my opinion- your suggested formula would be an overkill. It is to the OP to decide.

Comment: @marikamitsos yeah, that formula is a bit long :) but a locale-independent solution. Also why `--`? With right locale it will convert the string to a datetime value, am I right? That is really nice if so.

Comment: @JvdV You are correct. `REGEXREPLACE`  is more greedy compared to `SUBSTITUTE`. If you don't mind I could add your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Go ahead @marikamitsos

Comment: @kishkin *"why --?"* It is not about the locale. The result deriving from the `REGEXREPLACE` as well the `SUBSTITUTE` formula is text. So it needs to be converted to a number. That is why we use `--`. One could also use (in the end of the formula) `+0` or `^1`. **Locale kicks in after the conversion**

Comment: @marikamitsos it won't be converted to a number if it cannot be interpreted as detetime. And that depends on locale. Right?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1 - getting datetime value

You can convert those kind of strings using formula without setting up the formatting in the menu:

```
= DATE(
    REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "\d{4}"),
    MATCH(
      LOWER(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "^\w+")),
      {"jan"; "feb"; "mar"; "apr"; "may"; "jun"; "jul"; "aug"; "sep"; "oct"; "nov"; "dec"},
      0
    ),
    REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "\s(\d{2}),")
  )
+ TIME(
    MOD(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(\d+):") + IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, "(?i)\s(?:(?:0?\d|1[^2]):\d+pm|12:\d+am)$"), 12, 0), 24),
    REGEXEXTRACT(A2, ":(\d{2})"),
    0
  )
```

[image]

Then `C1` has formatted datetime using this formula:

```
=TEXT(B2, "dd/m/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

### Solution 2 - getting just the right string

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
  SUBSTITUTE(
    REGEXREPLACE(
      A2,
      "(?i)^\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+\d+:(\d+)(?:PM|AM)$",
      "$1/month/$2 hour:$3:00"
    ),
    "month",
    MATCH(
      LOWER(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "^\w+")),
      {"jan"; "feb"; "mar"; "apr"; "may"; "jun"; "jul"; "aug"; "sep"; "oct"; "nov"; "dec"},
      0
    )
  ),
  "hour",
  MOD(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(\d+):") + IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, "(?i)\s(?:(?:0?\d|1[^2]):.+pm|12:.+am)$"), 12, 0), 24)
)
```

[image]